# Documenting a latex package from comments

Tags: documentation

I have just completed writing my very own LaTex package, how can i make the package to be self documented like maybe from comments in the package code?

Comment: package `ltxdoc`, where the .dtx file can provide both the documentation as well as the .sty file

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've written the package as a `.sty` file, a good start at a combined source code/documentation is provided by the Perl script [`sty2dtx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sty2dtx) (requires Perl). The script also works for document classes with the `--type class` switch.

Usage:

```bash
perl sty2dtx.pl < mypkg.sty > mypkg.dtx
```

or

```bash
perl sty2dtx.pl mypkg.sty mypkg.dtx
```

Refer to the [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/sty2dtx/README) for a complete list of supported options.

The script generates a `.dtx` file for use in the workflow described in [How to Package Your LaTeX Package](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/dtxtut/dtxtut.pdf). The generated `.dtx` forms a starting point by showing any comments in your `.sty` file as text in documentation generated by running `(pdf)latex` on the `.dtx` file.

This will give you a good starting point for a package in the literate programming style, with generated documentation in the style of many LaTeX packages. From here, it's up to you to add content to the documentation within the base framework provided by `sty2dtx`.